# Создание многомерного массива строк из структуры данных в Golang

Tags: массивы, golang, структуры, структуры-данных, golang-struct

Делаю программу, которая выводит результат запроса из MySQL на экран в табличном виде при помощи библиотеки gotabulate. Данная библиотека принимает многомерные массивы строк на вход (ниже отрывок из ее документации):

```
// Some Strings
string_1 := []string{"TV", "1000$", "Sold"}
string_2 := []string{"PC", "50%", "on Hold"}

// Create Object
tabulate := gotabulate.Create([][]string{string_1, string_2})
```

У меня есть следующий код:

```
type book struct {
    title       string
    name_author string
}
books := []book{}
// Тут идет запрос в MySQL
for rows.Next() {
    b := book{}
    err := rows.Scan(&b.title, &b.name_author)
    books = append(books, b)
}
```

Затем я пытаюсь разобрать получившийся массив и создать на его основе одномерный массив но выходит сообщение что я не могу вставить объект типа []string в массив (cannot use string_1 (variable of type []string) as string value in argument to append):

```
strings_massive := [][]string{}
for _, book := range books {
    string_1 := []string{book.title, book.name_author}
    strings_massive[0] = append(strings_massive[0], string_1)
}
```

Подскажите как создать нормальный многомерный массив для работы с gotabulate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ваша проблема состоит в том что вы добавляете список строк туда где должна быть просто строка.

Ведь сообщение об ошибки говорит:

> невозможно использовать string_1 (переменную типа []string) в качестве значения string в аргументе append

Попробуйте так:

```go
...

strings_massive := [][]string{}
for _, book := range books {
    string_1 := []string{book.title, book.name_author}
    strings_massive = append(strings_massive, string_1)
//                ^^                       ^^
}
```